# Descriptive Statistics comparing groups and frequency

Tags: r, datatable, statistics, data-visualization, categorical-data

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
'data.frame':   200005 obs. of  23 variables:
 $ ID                                   : chr  "A16000" "A17000" "A17000" "A17000" "A18000"...
 $ Date                                 : Date, format: "2018-04-10" "2017-03-21" "2017-04-22" "2017-05-09" ...
 $ Educ                                 : num  0 1 0 0 1 NA NA 1 NA NA ...
 $ Returned                             : num  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ Burrowed                             : num  "7" "45" "10" "10" ...
 $ Freq                                 : num  "1" "10" "10" "2" ...
 $ Grp                                  : chr  NA "A" "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "A" ...
```

and I want to find some descriptive statistics answers using it but I don't know what would be the best codes. I want to know: 1: does group A Return more than Group B? 2: Do customers with higher Freq burrow more? 3: Are customers with 10 or higher Freq more likely to have Educ?

I have tried using different tables, but they bring back long strings of values I can't make heads or tails of. Example of what I've tried:

```
#Comparison of returns by Groups
xtabs(~df$Returned+df$Grp,data=df)
rowPerc(xtabs(~df$Returned+df$Grp,data=df)) #numerical summary of variable
bargraph(~df$Grp,groups=df$Returned,data=df,type="percent") #graphical summary of variable
favstats(~df$Grp|df$Returned,data=df) #numerical summary of variable
bwplot(df$Returned~df$Grp,data=df)
```

But no matter what it just spits out a whole set that has like 200 rows which is not what i want and looks something like this:

```
  A        B                                   C    D     E                        F                    G
  0      21649                                 3 39218   477                      55                    87
  1        671                                 0  1491    22                       2                     0
  2        527                                 0   742     7                       1                     0
  3        328                                 0   410     1                       0                     0
  4        227                                 0   236     4                       1                     0
  5        340                                 0   395     1                       0                     0
  6        160                                 0   165     1                       1                     3
  7        117                                 0   146     1                       0                     0
  8        118                                 0   181     1                       0                     0
```

And continue for like 20 rows? What would be a better way of comparing this data and answering the questions?

Comment: Some of your variables are characters, but you probably want them to be numerical. For example: Returned. Change their type to numeric and it will work!

Comment: Ok, I did that and it does help. but the return is just a whole bunch of strings of data. Are there better tables to visualize the data to answer these questions?

Answer (score 0):

The function 'count' in 'dplyr' will do this for you

```
data.frame %>% count(Grp)
```